# How do I replace a sequence of characters but not if they are part of a bigger word?

Tags: vba, excel-2013

Say I want to replace the string `BASE` with `STUFF` but not in `BASELESS` or `BASED`. Here is the original string:

`THE BASE OF THIS STATEMENT IS A BASELESS BASE`

and I want it to read:

`THE STUFF OF THIS STATEMENT IS A BASELESS STUFF`

I've got something like this

```
Dim myString As String : myString = "THE BASE OF THIS STATEMENT IS A BASELESS BASE"
myString = Replace(myString, "BASE ", "STUFF ")
If Right(myString, 4) = "BASE" Then
  myString= Left(myString,Len(myString)-4) & "STUFF"
End If
```

But is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim regEx
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "BASE(?!\w)"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = True
myString= regEx.Replace(myString, "STUFF")
```

Comment: /g is 'global', search the pattern in every part of the string.. try now!